# Which IP and port should I use for MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, ip, database-connection, port

I've only recently installed MSSQL and I want to connect to my DB with Python.

- However when I look up my IP with canyouseeme.org it tells me, my IP is 193.x.x.x
- However if I open TCP/IP protocol for SQLExpress through SQL Configuration manager my IP4 IP is shown as 192.x.x.x.
- With IPconfig in CMD my IP shows up again as 192.x.x.x.

Can somebody please explain this to me? Or point me to a clear "MSSQL server for dummies" tutorial which covers this? Given I'm not able to find it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check your IP from canyouseeme.org it's showing you a public IP address that let you connect to the internet. But when you use IPconfig in cmd or in your SQL configuration manager you are getting your local IP for your device, this IP is given to you by your router whereas your public IP is assigned to you by your ISP.

So you should use your local IP in your case 192.xxx, you won't be able to access it out side your local network also.